# Locking sheet not working as intended

Tags: excel, vba

I want to lock/unlock a given sheet based on the value of a cell in another sheet.
I wrote the following code in worksheet change for sheet `form`:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Status = Sheets("form").Range("J2")
If Status = "Active" Then
    Sheets("overview").Unprotect "password"
    'MsgBox "The template is now unlocked"
Else
    Sheets("overview").Protect "password"
    'MsgBox "The template is locked"
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

However, when `Status` is other than `active` I can still change some cells in `overview` getting a "Unable to set the hidden property of the Range class" popup.
Where is the error?

Comment: where do you have this code written ? in which module or Worksheet event do you have it ? I just tested it and it works on my Excel Workbook.

Comment: try the code below, it's working when i'm changing the value of "J2" cell in `form` worksheet.

Comment: I don't know if it is pertinent, but the value in J2 can be selected from a drop down list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code on **Worksheet_Change** event (in your `form` worksheet code) :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Status = Me.Range("J2")
    If Status = "Active" Then
        Sheets("overview").Unprotect "password"
        'MsgBox "The template is now unlocked"
    Else
        Sheets("overview").Protect "password"
        'MsgBox "The template is locked"
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Tryed, most of the cells are locked, but I am still able to select and type in columns A, G, J...

Comment: did you select and locked these cells manualy before running this code ?

Comment: the lock cells and hide formulas checkboxes were full. After checking them, the behavior is as expected.